# Live update of html content without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

So I'm trying to make simple Flask web where I'd display crypto prices, which I get from api.

My problem is that I have no idea how to keep live updating prices without refreshing website. I've been trying to use some js scripts which i've found online but none of them worked.

Here's my sample of code
Function to get api. It return list of dictionaries, each dict refers to one crypto

```
def liveTicker():
    url = f'https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=20'
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    return data['data']
```

Example

[{"id":"bitcoin","rank":"1","symbol":"BTC","name":"Bitcoin","priceUsd":"26624.0202717885229141"}]

Then I make app.route and pass that information to my HTML

```
@app.route('/cryptonitetop20', methods=['GET','POST'])
def cryptonitetop20():
    top20price = liveTicker()
    return jsonify(top20price)

@app.route('/main', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    if 'user' in session:
        info = db.checkRegToken(session.get("user"))
        top20price = cryptonitetop20()
        return render_template('main.html', result = top20price.json ) 
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Using loop I create all data which I need

```
        <ul>
            {% for item in result %}
                <li id="{{ item.rank }}"><img src ="https://assets.coincap.io/assets/icons/{{ item.symbol.lower() }}@2x.png"> {{ item.symbol }} {{   item.priceUsd | float | round(2) }}$</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

And now comes the problem how to live update that content.

I've tried to use this script but its failing

```
        <script>
            setInterval(function() {
                    fetch('/cryptonitetop20').then(
                        response => response.json()
                    ).then(
                        data => 
                            data.forEach(item =>
                                updateElement(item)
                            )
                    )
                }, 10000
            );
            function updateElement(item) {
                Object.entries(item).forEach(([k,v]) => {
                    element = document.getElementById(item.rank);
                    // Get Previous value first
                    previousValue = element.innerHTML;

                    // If Previous value is not equal to the new value, change it!
                    if (previousValue !== v.toString()) {
                        element.innerHTML = v.toString();
                    }
                })
            }

        </script>
```

But it throws error

main:72 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Can anyone help me to fix this or find any other work-around to make it work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to check that element exists in the DOM first before reading it? element = document.getElementById(item.rank);
  if (element) {
// Get Previous value first..ect... }

Comment: @user1857654 Yes, problem occurs with this line     v.toString())   . It prints in console element, but cannot get the new value for that element